# Is it possible to associate models in two different ways?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, has-many

I have a User model which has many Committees a Committee also belongs to a user.

Because users are a mixture of Admins and regular web users, I've developed a new concept, where a User can favorite a Committee.

Is it possible to associate the User and Committee models in a second way?

Where a user:

```
has_many :favorites
has_many :committees, through: :favorites
```

Obviously this will collide with the above User.first.committees but is there a way I could use another noun but still keep the basic through logic?

This would be awesome if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have two associations to the same model. Something like this.

```
has_many :committees
has_many :favorites
has_many :favorite_committees, through: :favorites
```

Thus you will have three models User, Committee and Favorite.

You can also refer this.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Mixing UK and US spelling there.

Comment: Sorry about that. Corrected. :)